# React Native interpolate background color not working with rgba alpha transparency

Tags: react-native, animation, interpolation, background-color, rgba

I want to interpolate the `backgroundColor` of a `View`.

This is my `animation:`

```
const [myAnimation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
const setInteraction = (focused) => {
            if (focused) {
                Animated.timing(myAnimation, {
                    toValue: 1,
                    duration: 160,
                    useNativeDriver: false,
                }).start();
            }

            if (!focused) {
                Animated.timing(myAnimation, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 160,
                    useNativeDriver: false,
                }).start();
            }

            return;
        };
```

And here is how I use it to interpolate the `backgroundColor`:

```
 <Animated.View
     style={{
              backgroundColor: myAnimation.interpolate({
                   inputRange: [0, 1],
                   outputRange: [
                      'rgba(27,43,89,0.06)',
                      'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                   ],
               }),
             }}
            >
   {...}
</Animated.View>
```

The problem is that since the initial color has a 6% opacity it doesn't work 100% as I expected. It goes from the initial color to an intermediate one and finally ends up in the target color (white):

https://recordit.co/czrVd5Q38I

If the color was 100% opaque it will work, for example:

```
<Animated.View
     style={{
              backgroundColor: myAnimation.interpolate({
                   inputRange: [0, 1],
                   outputRange: [
                      'rgba(27,43,89,1)',
                      'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                   ],
               }),
             }}
            >
   {...}
</Animated.View>
```

https://recordit.co/HSvJNV4ldg

Any ideas? I've tried playing with the `inputRange` property but still doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**

I've realised that the problem is the white color as a target. If I try playing with the `alpha` value of the same initial / target color it works:

```
outputRange: [
   'rgba(27,43,89,0.06)',
   'rgba(27,43,89,0.1)',
],
```

Comment: Have you tried animating between solid colors, and animating the opacity separately?

Comment: @Abe Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it didn't work:

https://recordit.co/LfvmV5d7Yq

Comment: Can you post the code of what you tried?  Also, I don't think this is your issue, but you don't need to save the Animated.Value in state.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, hex or others work fine

```
  backgroundColor: interpolateColor(
    progress.value,
    [0, 1],
    ['red', 'blue']
  ),
```

but alpha channels broke everything

```
  backgroundColor: interpolateColor(
    progress.value,
    [0, 1],
    ['rgba(255, 51, 51, 0.5)', 'rbg(116, 255, 51, 0.5)']
  ),
```

not really new issues for reanimated lib https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/discussions/1552